# Conditionals for flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexer

Is is possible to place conditional statements for rules in flex? I need this in order to match a specific rule only when some condition is true. Something like this:

```
%option c++
%option noyywrap

%%
/*if (condition) {*/
[0-9] {}
/*}*/
[0-9]{2} {}
.     /* eat up any unmatched character */
%%

void yylex(void);

int main()
{
    FlexLexer *lexer = new yyFlexLexer();
    lexer->yylex();
    delete lexer;
}
```

Or is it possible to modify the final c++ generated code, in order to match only some specific regex rules?

**UPDATE:**

Using start conditions doesn't seem to help. What I want is, depending on some external variable (like isNthRegexActive), to be able to match or not a specific regex.
For example, if I have 4 regex rules, and the first and 2nd are not active, the program should only check for the other 2, and always check for all of them (don't stop at first match - maybe use REJECT).

Example for 4 rules:

```
/* Declared at the top */
isActive[0] = false;
isActive[1] = false;
isActive[2] = true;
isActive[3] = true;

%%
[0-9]{4} { printf("1st: %s\n", yytext); REJECT;}
[0-3]{2}[0-3]{2} { printf("2nd: %s\n", yytext); REJECT; }
[1-3]{2}[0-3]{2} { printf("3rd: %s\n", yytext); REJECT; }
[1-2]{2}[1-2]{2} { printf("4th: %s\n", yytext); REJECT; }
.
%%
```

For the input: `1212` the result should be:

```
3rd: 1212
4th: 1212
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-Greedy Regular Expression Matching in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488772/non-greedy-regular-expression-matching-in-flex)

Comment: My answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488772/non-greedy-regular-expression-matching-in-flex/29730842#29730842 show you how to use states in flex to achieve this.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 thank you for the link, but I don't think that solves my problem. I have updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You have invented a mechanism you cannot implement but not explained the real problem itself. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 You can think of it like having an UI, from which you can select using a checkbox what to match (1st option = first regex, ... 4th option = 4th regex). The checkboxes selected will translate into the regexes that will try to match the input.
The condition itself (isActive[i]) is whether the checkbox is checked (regex will try to match) or not (regex will not try to match - as if it was not written in the file)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `REJECT` unless you absolutely have no alternative. It massively slows down the lexical scan, artificially limits the size of the token buffer, and makes your lexical analysis very hard to reason about.

You might be thinking that a scanner generated by (f)lex tests each regular expression one at a time in order to select the best one for a given match. It does not work that way; that would be much too slow. What it does is, effectively, check all the regular expressions in parallel by using a precompiled deterministic state machine represented as a lookup table.

The state machine does exactly one transition for each input byte, using a simple O(1) lookup into the the transition table. (There are different table compression techniques which trade off table size against the constant in the O(1) lookup, but that doesn't change the basic logic.) What that all means is that you can use as many regular expressions as you wish; the time to do the lexical analysis does not depend on the number or complexity of the regular expressions. (Except for caching effects: if your transition table is really big, you might start running into cache misses during the transition lookups. In such cases, you might prefer a compression algorithm which compresses more.)

In most cases, you can use start conditions to achieve conditional matching, although you might need a lot of start conditions if there are a more than a few interacting conditions. Since the scanner can only have one active start condition, you'll need to generate a different start condition for each legal combination of the conditions you want to consider. That's usually most easily achieved through automatic generation of your scanner rules, but it can certainly be done by hand if there aren't too many.

It's hard to provide a more concrete suggestion without knowing what kinds of conditions you need to check.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how flex actually works. However, I don't know if what I want to achieve is possible. what I want to achieve is this:
You can think of it like having an UI, from which you can select using a checkbox what to match (1st option = first regex, ... 4th option = 4th regex). The checkboxes selected will translate into the regexes that will try to match the input.
The condition itself is whether the checkbox is checked (regex will try to match) or not (regex will not try to match - as if it was not written in the file)

Comment: @liviu: if you have four checkboxes, you have 16 possible combinations, so you need 16 start conditions. When your UI changes, recompute the start condition and enable it with BEGIN. You could do that by hand, but personally I'd write a script. If you had 8 checkboxes, you've got 256 combinations and a script is pretty well mandatory. At some point, your table size will blow up -- but then, so will your UI :-)

Comment: Note: you can insert code in yylex which runs on entry, which might be a good place to compute the start condition and call BEGIN. Also, you can redefine yylex's prototype so that you can pass through arguments, which can avoid the need for globals.